# Exception in thread "UdpClientThread_1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonSyntaxException

Tags: java, gson, udpclient

Im running a Java maven project and am using an sdk provided to me by a certain company
and I keep getting an error:

> > > > Exception in thread "UdpClientThread_1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonSyntaxException
> > > > at novj.platform.vxkit.handy.api.SearchManager.onPacketReceived(SearchManager.java:172)
> > > > at novj.publ.net.udp.UdpSession.onReceived(UdpSession.java:99)
> > > > at novj.publ.net.udp.UdpClient$1.run(UdpClient.java:93)
> > > > at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
> > > > Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException
> > > > at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
> > > > at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
> > > > at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)

Here's the code

```
    package org.example;

import novj.platform.vxkit.common.bean.search.SearchResult;
import novj.platform.vxkit.handy.api.SearchManager;
import novj.publ.api.NovaOpt;
import novj.publ.net.exception.ErrorDetail;

// Press Shift twice to open the Search Everywhere dialog and type `show whitespaces`,
// then press Enter. You can now see whitespace characters in your code.
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NovaOpt novaOpt = NovaOpt.GetInstance();
        SearchManager.OnScreenSearchListener searchListener = new SearchManager.OnScreenSearchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SearchResult searchResult) {
                System.out.printf("Connection to target successful");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ErrorDetail errorDetail) {
                System.out.printf("Connection to target unsuccessful");
            }
        };
        novaOpt.searchScreen(searchListener , "172.24.100.75");
    }
}
```

Anyone solved this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Downloading the gson library and adding it as a library solved the problem.